# Xpath from a span text in break

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the validate the $40 by asserting but unable to track the xpath. Any Suggestions

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12"><div class="vetting-details"><h3 class="paragraph text-center"><span>Vetting Price: </span>$40 <br> <span>Estimated Time for Vetting:</span> 30 seconds</h3></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `40` is basically a `text node`. You can retrieve it using :

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@class,'paragraph text-center')]"));
String el = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", e);
String s  = el.split("\\ ")[2].trim();
System.out.println(s)
```

**Explanation :**

`40` is not a plain text rather it is a text node. we need JS intervention to target the `p` tag, and then get all the text content. Then using split to split the string to get the desired element.

Comment: when I executed- Got this - org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')

Comment: Updated above, please try again

Comment: Shows NPE for System.out.println(el.getAttribute('innerText'));

Comment: @SobhitSharma : Please try now.

Comment: Works like a charm. Explanation?

Comment: @SobhitSharma : Please see above !

Answer (score 0):

We can use below code (without JavaScriptExecutor)

```
 String value=driver.findElement(By.tagName("h3")).getText();
        String s1=value.split(":")[1].trim();
        System.out.println(s1);
```